# How to customize different error messages for the same field?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have the following field that uses it's own regular expression to validate:

```
<input type="text" name="first-name" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" 
       data-parsley-trigger="change" required data-parsley-alpha data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z]*$"/>
```

The field has multiple validation failure states, and I want each of those states to have a different error message.

For example, if the user enters a space, I want the error message to say "No spaces allowed", but if it has a numeric character, I want the error message to say "No numbers allowed".

I've tried to figure out how to do this by reading the docs, but I'm still confused on how to achieve this.

I'm using Parsley `2.0.0-rc4`

Comment: input.setCustomValidity()

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use that function in this case?

Comment: This is better done outside a framework; why not test the input's value directly with regex or indexOf?

Comment: @Algorath I've been thinking more and more  and leaning toward dropping parsley and rolling my own complete solution. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @NathanJones this is the thing. Validation logic, messaging and interacting with the DOM are simple problems for people with a good handle on Javascript and the DOM. Multiple failure state messaging, validation hierarchy logic aren't. The shocking thing is that the really popular libraries only deal with the simple stuff that isn't really a difficult problem in the first place, while making it harder to do the actually complex stuff because you have to hook into their limited APIs. Please let us know how you end up dealing with this if it's a non-parsley solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is not something easily doable with Parsley. Each validator have an unique error message.

If you want to do so, for UI/UX purposes, you may have two possibilities:

1) You'll need to define some custom validators of yours, and their related messages.

In your example:

- create a validator `nospaces` and its message with 66 priority
- create a validator `nonumbers` and its message with a 65 priority
- still use your `pattern` validator (64 priority) and eventually change its message by something like 'only alphanum allowed'

Add then these 3 validators to your input, and depending on their respective priority they would be fired in the right order to display the right error message you want as described in your question.

Pros: easily reusable
Cons: some work is needed

2) Keep your pattern validator, and bind a custom function to the `parsley:field:error` event for this input, and do your check to display the right error message you want for this field, and not the default one

Pros: less work maybe, in a single function
Cons: not much reusable

Comment: Could you show me how to customize the error message? All of my attempts to use [updateError](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript) only sort of works. In the debugger, if I pause right after the `updateError` function is called, my error message does display, but after resuming the error message gets changed back to the default error message. If you'd like to see my attempt to use `updateError`, I'd be happy to edit my question to show that.

Comment: Eh, disregard that last comment. I'm going with your first possibility. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: There might be an issue with updateError function. I'll have a look. Best